# Configuration issues with lemur CGI

Tags: search, configuration, search-engine, lemur, indri

I'm trying to get a simple lemur CGI up and running, but when I navigate to lemur.cgi in my browser, I get a 500 server configuration error.

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I built the index by running IndriBuildIndex in `~/indri_test/param_files/`. This created a subdirectory with the same name as the index, `./krovetz_stop`.

I'm able to query the index manually using IndriRunQuery without issue.

I followed a tutorial to set-up the CGI which had me perform the following steps:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir ~/public_html
$ chmod 711 ~/
$ cd public_html
$ cp -r ~/indri-5.1/site-search/cgi/bin/* ~/public_html
$ chmod 775 lemur.cgi
$ chcon -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t lemur.cgi
```

I then updated the `lemur.config` file in `~/public_html` to point to my index (more formally, I'm pointing it to the subdirectory that was  created when I built the index, because otherwise I'm not sure what the "path to the index" is). Here's my lemur.config file:

```
<lemurconfig>
  <templatepath>./templates/</templatepath>
  <supportanchortext>true</supportanchortext>
  <indexes>
    <index>
      <path>/home/user/indri_test/param_files/krovetz_stop/</path>
      <description>Krovetz stemmer, no stop words</description>
    </index>
  </indexes>
</lemurconfig>
```

As far as I can tell everything should work, but it's not. Maybe I need to rebuild the CGI with autotools? Any ideas what steps I can take to debug the problem? Maybe I'm not using the correct path to the index? Do I need to modify permissions on the index directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue after all. Resolved via:

```
chmod 755 ~/public_html
```